# GKE Standard creation fails with "PERMISSIONS_ERROR" for service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

**Problem:**
I'm facing an issue creating a GKE Standard cluster in the GCP console. I've assigned the necessary permissions to a custom service account and selected it during cluster creation, but the process fails with the following error message:

```
    PERMISSIONS_ERROR: Instance 'gke-cluster-1-default-pool-04d4bc2e' creation failed: Required 'compute.instances.create' permission for 'projects/874xxxxxxx/zones/us-central1-c/instances/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-04d4bc2e' (when acting as '874xxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com');
... (other permission errors listed)
```

**Details:**

I dont know from where it has picking up this service account service account ("874xxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com")
The service account which I have choosen is different then the one mentioned in the error and I couldnt find this services account in IAM service section.

**Question:**

I'm unsure of what additional permissions are needed or which service account I should be using ? Can anyone help me understand the error and suggest the correct service account and permissions for creating a GKE Standard cluster?

**Please Note:** I've intentionally redacted sensitive information like project ID and service account name for security purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [gcp documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#google_apis_service_agent):

> This service account is designed specifically to run internal Google processes on your behalf. The account is owned by Google and is not listed in the Service Accounts section of Google Cloud console. By default, the account is automatically granted the project editor role on the project and is listed in the IAM section of Google Cloud console. This service account is only deleted when the project is deleted. However, you can change the roles granted to this account, including revoking all access to your project.

This service account is essential for creating GKE cluster successfully. Without correct permissions, cluster creation will fail regardless of the user account or service account you are using.

To fix this issue, you should:

1. Go to [IAM page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam).
2. Check `Include Google-provided role grants` above the table on the right side. Now you should see all permissions including accounts managed by Google.
3. Grant `874xxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` the appropriate permissions (It is **Editor** by default). If you didn't find it, you can click `GRANT ACCESS` and add it manually with the proper permissions.

Hope this helps! :)